# mysql query question about having and count

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, mariadb

In this query*, I list and sort rows from "mytableabc"  by latitude, longitude, various criterias,... from near to far or score and its working/listing datas and i think its good/fast enought!?

```
select 
round((6371 * acos(cos(radians('40.123456')) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longtitude) - radians('29.123456')) + sin(radians(latitude)) * sin(radians('40.123456')))), (2)) as distance, 
    (match(colone,coltwo) against('searchkeywordabc' in boolean mode)) as score, 
id,colone,coltwo,latitude,longtitude,colthree 
        from mytableabc 
        where (colone='sampleforsomething') 
            and (match(colone,coltwo) against('searchkeywordabc' in boolean mode))
                having distance <= 5 order by distance asc limit 0,50
```

**--problem**

in different lines and files i need only total number count(id) of returning elements with same criterias...
i try to add count(id), but its not gives correct count total and also list lines, **i just want total numbers(as normally count query does) not data line**

```
select 
    count(id), 
round((6371 * acos(cos(radians('40.123456')) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longtitude) - radians('29.123456')) + sin(radians(latitude)) * sin(radians('40.123456')))), (2)) as distance, 
        (match(colone,coltwo) against('searchkeywordabc' in boolean mode)) as score, 
    id,colone,coltwo,latitude,longtitude,colthree 
            from mytableabc 
            where (colone='sampleforsomething') 
                and (match(colone,coltwo) against('searchkeywordabc' in boolean mode))
                    having distance <= 5 order by distance asc limit 0,50
```

**--also this query without distance/latitude/longtitude criteria works good, returning only total number... but i need to add distance query to this query**

```
select count(id) from mytableabc where (colone='sampleforsomething') and (match(colone,coltwo) against('searchkeywordabc' in boolean mode))
```

i'm not sql expert and yes as you see i need one.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

Move the `distance` check to the `WHERE` clause.  This eliminates the need for `HAVING` while filtering more, so that the `COUNT` won't be inflated.

```
select  count(*)
    from  mytableabc
    where  (colone='sampleforsomething')
      and  (match(colone,coltwo) against('searchkeywordabc' in boolean mode))
      AND  (6371 * acos(cos(radians('40.123456')) * 
        cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longtitude) -
        radians('29.123456')) + sin(radians(latitude)) *
        sin(radians('40.123456')))) < 5;
```

I expect the `FULLTEXT` index to be used first, with the other two tests (`=` and distance) being checked for all rows returned from the FT search.

Plan B:

Continue to use `HAVING`, but have a subquery.  (This is probably slower.)

Comment: i analyze/benchmark and plan a selected. thank you for quick reply